# How to make this alternate scrolling text NOT to go beyond its parent element's width or sides?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text scrolling back and forth alternatively within its parent container. However the text is scrolling but with one issue: text goes beyond its parent container's width or sides and then scrolls back. I want text to scroll left to right and right to left as soon as it touches its parents left and right borders.

Can anyone please help me to make some editing in my below code so that I can achieve my desired result:

```css
.text_scroll {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text_scroll_alt > p {
  width: max-content;
  padding-left: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  animation: scroll_alt 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes scroll_alt {
  to {transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="text_scroll text_scroll_alt">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am looking for suitable answer too, because I met those problem before. Then, I used fixed width to parent, and child to solve it.

Comment: @SatoTakeru fixed width is not a perfect solution in year 2021 when we all intended to develop websites for mobile too, but just a quick fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make < p > Absolute and give left position in keyframe to achieve this.

I have used translateX to subtract the dynamic width of element.

```css
.text_scroll {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position:relative;
  min-height:50px
}

.text_scroll_alt > p {
   width: max-content;
   position:absolute;
   border: 1px solid red;
   animation: scroll_alt 5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes scroll_alt {
    from {transform:translateX(0);left:0;}
    to {transform:translateX(-100%);left:100%}
}
```

```html
<div class="text_scroll text_scroll_alt">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the logic behind value 360px that you used in `calc()`?

Comment: It is the width of the your element <p> I subtracted its width from left position so it will not overflow container.

Comment: Hope it clears the logic behind.

Comment: I speculated the same but... how did you find out that my `<p>` element's width is 360px? I don't see any static width written for this element in my code. Also what if the text within this element increases or decreases? Will your static width work then?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer with respect to dynamic width of your <p> element. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Reference taken from https://www.quackit.com/css/codes/marquees/

```css
 .example5 {
     height: 50px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: relative;
}
 .example5 h3 {
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     line-height: 50px;
     text-align: left;
    /* Apply animation to this element */
     -moz-animation: example5 5s linear infinite alternate;
     -webkit-animation: example5 5s linear infinite alternate;
     animation: example5 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
/* Move it (define the animation) */
 @-moz-keyframes example5 {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateX(70%);
    }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
 @-webkit-keyframes example5 {
     0% {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(70%);
    }
     100% {
         -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
 @keyframes example5 {
     0% {
         -moz-transform: translateX(70%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
         -webkit-transform: translateX(70%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
         transform: translateX(70%);
    }
     100% {
         -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
         -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
        /* Firefox bug fix */
         transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="example5">
  <h3>Bouncing text..</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Not worth at all. I already knew this site's reference.